# how to create an Enter event for textbox in wpf xaml code?

Tags: wpf, xaml, enter

I am fresh to wpf,start learning xaml last 3days,when i am creating the enter event for my textbox in xaml code i cont create y? how can i create enter evnet? some events no proble like click,textchanged events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "Enter" event in WPF textbox.
You should think of other events like :
GotFocus,
MouseEnter,
MouseDown,
GotKeybordFocus
Depending what you need.

In xaml you write sth like :`<TextBox Height="23" Canvas.Left="374" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Canvas.Top="272" Width="120" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus_1"/>`

but it's easier to use designer.
Properties->Events -> doubleClick on the event you need to generate for control.

Answer (score 0):

You want it only if the user press Enter when the focus is in the TextBox?

What you can do if your design is MVVM with commands:

At the same level as Window.Resources:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding EnterCommand}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

But this will catch the Enter key anywhere in your window, not just if your focusing your TextBox...

Comment: Thanks for ur reply,i want to create enter event for text box as like normal windows text box.the purpose is whenever i enter into text box select the text. like normal win app textbox.selectall()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextChanged` event and the code for the handler,

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```